# Symfony2 form: automatically add NotBlank constraint and Bootstrap Validator message for required fields

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

When building a form in Symfony2 with validation and custom error messages for required fields, I manually have to specify NotBlank constraints and custom error message attributes for client side validation (using Bootstrap Validator). The code looks like so for every form field:

```
$builder->add('name', 'text', array(
    'required' => true,
    'constraints' => array(
      new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Bitte geben Sie Ihren Namen ein.')),
    ),
    'attr' => array(
      // This is for client side bootstrap validator
      'data-bv-notempty-message' => 'Bitte geben Sie Ihren Namen ein.'
    )
));
```

What I am looking for is the possibility to make this shorter by specifying the required_message only once:

```
$builder->add('name', 'text', array(
    'required_message' => 'Bitte geben Sie Ihren Namen ein.'
));
```

and I would like the builder to create the NotBlank constraint and the data-bv-notempty-message attribute.

What's the best way to achieve this? By creating a form type extension?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do what you're looking for. Symfony tends to be more verbose than other frameworks, but the upside is that it's especially clear to see what is going on. You'll encounter a lot more scenarios like this using Symfony so I would personally avoid this type of shortcut. If your forms represent doctrine entities/documents, I'd recommend using annotations there. Very easy to read, keeps your form class to a minimum, is reusable if you create multiple forms for your entity, and will save you a few characters.

Comment: Make yourself a textRequired form type.

Comment: @cristian, I'm using annotations on entity classes most of the time, but sometimes I have forms that are not bound to an entity or I want a field to be required in a certain form, but not in the entity. Also there are no annotations for adding html attributes for client side validation

Comment: @Cerad, I don't want to use only text fields, but all existing types

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm currently using is the following: In the type class of my form (or in the Controller class if creating forms on the fly without a Type class) I add a private function `addRequired` that I use for adding required fields like so:

```
class MyFormWithRequiredFieldsType extends AbstractType
{
    private $builder;
    private function addRequired($name, $type = null, $options = array())
    {
        $required_message = 'Bitte füllen Sie dieses Feld aus';
        if (isset($options['required_message'])) {
            $required_message = $options['required_message'];
            unset($options['required_message']);
        }
        $options['required'] = true;
        $options['attr']['data-bv-notempty-message'] = $required_message;
        if (!isset($options['constraints'])) {
            $options['constraints'] = array();
        }
        $options['constraints'][] = new NotBlank(array(
            'message' => $required_message
        ));
        $this->builder->add($name, $type, $options);
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->builder = $builder;
        $this->addRequired('name', 'text', array(
            'required_message' => 'Bitte geben Sie Ihren Namen ein'
        ));
    }
}
```

This works, but what I don't like about this solution is that for adding required fields I have to call `$this->addRequired()` instead of `$builder->add()` and so I loose the possibility of chaining the `add()`calls. That's why I'm looking for a solution to transparently override the `$builder->add()` method.

Comment: You can return the builder from addRequired method to be able to chain add calls.